# indexOf for multiple options

Tags: javascript, jquery

Let say, I get the following using `var content = this.innerHTML`:

```
w here&nbsp;</div>
```

Using `indexOf` (or other ways), I want to check for the first position that has either "Space", "<" or "&nbsp".

In this case, it will be 1 (after "w").

What I am confused about is how do I check for the very first position that has either one of these three choices? Do I use `Do...while` to check for individual "options"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably looking for a [Regular Expression (Regex)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) and the [String#search](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/search) method. Regex is a bit much to learn all at once, but I'll explain this example code.

You can use square brackets to denote a set of characters, so for example `[ <]` says "match either a space or a less-than sign."
You can use the pipe `|` to separate possibilities if you want to match one pattern or another, and that's how to account for matching a non-breaking space HTML entity.

```js
var string = 'w here&nbsp;</div>',
    index = string.search(/[ <]|&nbsp;/)
console.log(index) //=> 1
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Between `exec` and `search`, which is more efficient in terms of performance? Thanks.

Comment: `exec` provides more information, but `search` is likely more performant because no array must be constructed as a return value. `search` just gives you back a plain ol' number.

Comment: i See. Thank you for the reply!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regular expression with *alternations* (`|`), which means "match one of these things". That will also tell you what you found, if that's useful:

```js
function check(str) {
  var m = / |<|&nbsp;/.exec(str);
  if (!m) {
    console.log("Not found in '" + str + "'");
    return;
  }
  console.log("'" + m[0] + "' found at index " + m.index + " in '" + str + "'");
}

check("w here&nbsp;</div>");
check("where&nbsp;</div>");
check("where</div>");
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Between `exec` and `search`, which is more efficient in terms of performance? Thanks.

Comment: @steveKim: I doubt it really matters. `exec` returns more information, which could be handy, but that also means it may need to do more work. (Of course, it's entirely possible an implementation is doing that work behind the scenes anyway, and then just returning the index.) But you'd have to be calling it hundreds of thousands of times in a tight loop for it to matter. If it may be an issue for you, test the difference on your target environments.

Comment: Thank you T.J. Much appreciated! =)